# Docker is not correctly binding ports on windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, networking, docker

I am beginning to move my project to a docker container in order to be able to develop more stuff without depending too much on the OS I'm using.

This is the way I run my container:

`docker run -d -v "$(pwd)/app:/app" -v "/c/Users/Geoffrey/Projects/go:/go" --name "server" --link mysql:mysql -p 127.0.0.1:3000:3000 my/server:latest`

Quickly, my program executes an entrypoint launching my go app, listening port 3000.

Here is the Dockerfile associated with this container:

```
##
## Author: Geoffrey Bauduin <bauduin.geo@gmail.com>
##

## Use Ubuntu 14.04
FROM ubuntu:trusty

MAINTAINER Geoffrey Bauduin <bauduin.geo@gmail.com> 

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8

RUN echo "force-unsafe-io" > /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/02apt-speedup
RUN echo "Acquire::http {No-Cache=True;};" > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/no-cache

RUN echo $'#!/bin/sh\nexit 101' > /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d
RUN chmod +x /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d

## Installing gcc for go
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        g++ \
        gcc \
        libc6-dev \
        make \
        wget \
        git \
        ca-certificates \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV GOLANG_VERSION 1.5.3
ENV GOLANG_DOWNLOAD_URL http://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.5.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz

RUN wget "$GOLANG_DOWNLOAD_URL" \
    && tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.5.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz \
    && rm go1.5.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz

ENV GOPATH /go
ENV PATH $GOPATH/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:$PATH

RUN mkdir -p "$GOPATH/src" "$GOPATH/bin" && chmod -R 777 "$GOPATH"

COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 3000
```

When I browse `http://localhost:3000` from my windows host, Chrome returns `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`, same stuff for `127.0.0.1`, my network address (returned from `ipconfig`), even the container address (`docker inspect server | grep IPAddress`) is showing the same error message.
However, when I execute `/bin/bash` in my container, and then `curl localhost:3000`, I can see that the server is actually running on the expected port.

Is there something I'm missing ? Like why would Docker not be able to bind anything on my machine while it doesn't show any error messages ?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should change from `-p 127.0.0.1:3000:3000` to `-p 3000:3000` or use `-P` instead of them.